# i want to import a ascynchronus function in my app in node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

THe following code is my async code i want to import in my app.js file

```
module.exports = {
  foo : async () =>{
const axios = require('axios')
const [, pairA, pairB ] = require('./pairs.json')
const { SERVER_URL } = require('./lib/sdk')

const fundAccounts = async (pairs) => await Promise.all(
    pairs.map(
        async (pair) => await axios.get('/friendbot', {
            baseURL: SERVER_URL,
            params: { addr: pair.publicKey }
        })
    )
)

 fundAccounts([pairA, pairB])
    .then(() => console.log('ok'))
    .catch((e) => { console.error(e); throw e})
}
}
```

the following is my server.js file  trying to import and check the output

```
var funding = require('./scripts/2_fundAccounts');

console.log(typeof(funding));
console.log(funding.foo())
```

// i AM GETTING undifined

Next i tried with set time out method

```
function calling() {
var funding = require('./scripts/2_fundAccounts');
funding.foo()
}

setTimeout(calling,4000)
```

Any suggestions  how to import the code and make it work

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and so is off-topic. Other users won't be able to replicate this problem because `foo` won't be undefined if `./scripts/2_fundAccounts` looks like that. Eeither imported module doesn't look like you showed it, or you have circular dependency somewhere.

Comment: Hi estus you look very  experenced i will give you the github repo could you plese help me with importing the async code in app.js  and use it  please help  me

Comment: I cannot help you without https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Please, provide a way to replicate your problem in the question - a repo, etc. It doesn't have to be a project that contains proprietary code, just *minimal* example that shows the problem. As I said, the code you posted will work - unless you're imported wrong module.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
module.exports = async function foo () {
  // etc etc...
}
```

Comment: i tried  and to export  in my app.js  file 

funding = require('path ') 
funding.foo() 
it is showing me funding.foo() is not a function

Comment: and again i tried to see the typeof it is showing me ubndefined plese help me out